# Codeigniter loads only one view

Tags: php, codeigniter

All things works fine on localhost

The url is http://2015.thedubaibazaar.com/

The php version is 5.4

I am loading three views but it loads only one

```
    $this->load->view('_templates/header_one',$hdata    );
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
    $this->load->view('_templates/footer');
```

Then on the home controller I loaded only one view and it worked

I have tried debugging all issues but didn't got any errors

The hosting I use is softlayer

Thanks

Comment: Instead of loading such way try to load header and footer inside home page

Comment: yes that works but I guess that's not the correct way of loading multiple views

Comment: There are no such rules have been written that you can't load multiple views in that manner or its not the correct way of loading multiple views

Answer (score 1):

The important clue here is that you state...

> All things works fine on localhost

So which one Of the 3 Views does work on the server?

My guess would be the home one and the two that don't are the _templates folder views.

Comment: The footer view only loads , if i remove that it loads home_page only

Comment: Go back to basics - Just make some very simple views for your header, home and footer. For the Header - "This is the Header" , the home page -" This is the Home Page" and for the footer  "This is the Footer". SO the 3 views without any variables and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `true` to view

```
$this->load->view('_templates/header_one', $hdata, TRUE);
$this->load->view('home', $data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('_templates/footer', NULL, TRUE);
```

Try also make the templates folder views/templates rather than views/_templates

```
$this->load->view('templates/header_one',$hdata, TRUE);
$this->load->view('home', $data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', NULL, TRUE);
```

Edit/Update

```
$data['header_one'] = $this->load->view('templates/header_one', $hdata); // You May need to use true with header_one and footer 
$data['footer'] = $this->load->view('templates/footer');

$this->load->view('home', $data);
```

On view echo out header and footer

```
<?php echo $header;?>

Content Home

<?php echo $footer;?>
```

Comment: I updated my post try the new part make sure the templates folder matches

Comment: yes that will work , for home controller i loaded the header and footer view inside the homepage view
`$this->view('_teamplates/header_one');`
But then i will have to edit around 50 files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, echoing the view fixed it for me.

```
echo $this->load->view($theme_name . '/_parts/header_view', $data, true);
echo $this->load->view($theme_name . '/some_view', null, true);
echo $this->load->view($theme_name . '/_parts/footer_view', null, true);
```

I hope this helps.